# store infinity symbol in nvarchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to store a String in my SQL Database in a nvarchar column, that contains the character infinity '∞' and what I get is an eight '8' stored.
Any ideas why ? How should I manage this ?

```
 string = ' <ss:Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="3" ss:ExpandedRowCount="9"
          ss:DefaultColumnWidth="48.0" ss:DefaultRowHeight="12.75">
          <ss:Row ss:Index="3">
          <ss:Cell ss:Index="2">
          <ss:Data ss:Type="String">∞</ss:Data>
          </ss:Cell>
          <ss:Cell>
          <ss:Data ss:Type="String">∞</ss:Data>
          </ss:Cell>'
```

Comment: Tried escaped character?

Comment: tried and it stores the values that I insert : '&infin;', '&#8734;'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below SQL is working for me:

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'<ss:Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="3" ss:ExpandedRowCount="9"
          ss:DefaultColumnWidth="48.0" ss:DefaultRowHeight="12.75">
          <ss:Row ss:Index="3">
          <ss:Cell ss:Index="2">
          <ss:Data ss:Type="String">∞</ss:Data>
          </ss:Cell>
          <ss:Cell>
          <ss:Data ss:Type="String">∞</ss:Data>
          </ss:Cell>'

PRINT  @string
```

Answer (score 3):

Prefix your string with `N` i.e. `N'String....'` to explicitly tell sql server that you will be sending some `unicode` data and it should work.

```
Declare @t table (col nvarchar(4000))

Insert into @t
Values ( N' <ss:Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="3" ss:ExpandedRowCount="9"
          ss:DefaultColumnWidth="48.0" ss:DefaultRowHeight="12.75">
          <ss:Row ss:Index="3">
          <ss:Cell ss:Index="2">
          <ss:Data ss:Type="String">∞</ss:Data>
          </ss:Cell>
          <ss:Cell>
          <ss:Data ss:Type="String">∞</ss:Data>
          </ss:Cell>')


Select * from @t
```

Comment: Well cannot see this in the sample data you have added in your question. There are usually only two reasons for what you are experiencing , target column type is not `Nvarchar` (will not be able to store unicode data or the string you are trying to insert is not prefixed with `N`. If you show the exact query you are using maybe I can help you more.

Comment: @D.Tiberiu check all of it: column type, variable/parameter type, N' before literals.

Comment: Thanks, have checked and u are right, the update statement was correct but the column type was not. Changed it and works just fine !